# Java RSA Server Authentication - Is this secure?

Tags: java, authentication, encryption, client, rsa

I'm slightly new to RSA, and I'm attempting to make a server-client system where the client can only connect to the official server. The way I want to achieve this is with high bit rsa encryption. What I've done is create a random string of bits both from the server and client, combined them together, and had the client encrypt said bytes with the public key. This encrypted data is then sent to the server, for decryption, and after it is encrypted, it will be sent back to the client where it can check it against the original message, assuring that the server is indeed the one it is attempting to communicate with. My question is, is this secure as possible, using the specified bit length? (64 public key, 4096 private)

```
    public static boolean auth(DataInputStream in, DataOutputStream out) throws IOException {
    byte[] clientKey = new byte[2048];
    new SecureRandom().nextBytes(clientKey);
    out.write(clientKey);
    out.flush();

    byte[] serverKey = new byte[2048];
    in.readFully(serverKey);

    byte[] plainKey = new byte[4096];
    System.arraycopy(clientKey, 0, plainKey, 0, 2048);
    System.arraycopy(serverKey, 0, plainKey, 2048, 2048);

    byte[] encryptKey = new byte[4096];
    toByteArray(new BigInteger(1, plainKey).modPow(RSA_PUBLIC, RSA_MODULUS), encryptKey, 0, 4096);
    out.write(encryptKey);
    out.flush();

    byte[] serverAttempt = encryptKey;
    in.readFully(serverAttempt);

    return Arrays.equals(plainKey, serverAttempt);
}
```

Comment: Your scheme is no more secure than the server's private key. I suggest you don't bother. SSL authentication is already done. All you have to do is engage in SSL *and then verify that the server identity is authorised.* Home-grown cryptography is generally to be avoided if not deplored.

Comment: ssl is not secure enough for this application. can you elaborate on "no more secure than the server's private key"? Isn't that the point?

Comment: to elaborate, ssl does not support key length long enough nor stop MITM attacks

Comment: @Colby Your understanding of SSL appears flawed - the SSL protocol can handle any key length (certainly 4096 bit, and indeed much longer). If correctly implemented i.e. as EJP mentioned, by validating that the server is using the expected public key after authentication, then it prevents MITM attacks too.

Comment: @Iridium: His code is suggestive of using 4096 *byte* keys, as absurd as that seems.

Comment: @Iridium I don't understand how that would work. If all of the clients are using the same private key, wouldn't it be (relatively) easy to deduce the public key? My program won't be able to generate a unique private key for each client.

Comment: You state that you're trying to ensure that clients connect to the official server, if that's the case, there is only one private key - the server's, and only the server has access to it. The clients have the corresponding public key, which they can use during initiating an SSL connection that the server is "official".